# How to change the queryset returned based on the URL

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to make an educational site and have made a category system. There is a URL for each category and I need change the queryset returned based on the URL I am on. For example if I am on "localhost:8000/posts/category/3", I want my queryset returned to be:

```py
Post.objects.filter(category=3).order_by('-date_posted')
```

And so one depending on the URL.

I don't quite know where to start from for this.

The class based view that returns the queryset:

```py
class CatPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/science.html' #This is when you click a profile in a post, it takes you to his posts only
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 15

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(category=2).order_by('-date_posted')
```

urls.py (Contains only the part necessary):

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('post/category/<int:pk>/', CatPostListView.as_view(), name='category')
]
```

And just in case models.py:

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    class Meta:
        # enforcing that there can not be two categories under a parent with same slug

        # __str__ method elaborated later in post.  use __unicode__ in place of

        # __str__ if you are using python 2

        unique_together = ('slug', 'parent',)
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    display = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)#DON'T USE () HERE Just auto_now_ will show the date of the current day
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)#No () #This deletes the posts when the user is deleted


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

If I use the view i posted here that will not quite work. I need a method to take the pk from the url and put it in views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value from the URL:

```
return Post.objects.filter(category=self.kwargs['pk']).order_by('-date_posted')
```